# Mayer-Vietoris on $S^n$ - antipodal map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to do exercise 17.22 of Greenberg and Harper. The exercise is the following:

Let $a$ be the antipodal map, $E^+_n$ the north hemisphere and $E^-_n$ the south hemisphere of a sphere $S^n$, and consider the following commuting diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
(E^+_n,S^{n-1} ) & \rightarrow & (S^n, E^-_n) \\
a \downarrow & &  \downarrow a \\
(E^-_n,S^{n-1} ) & \rightarrow & (S^n, E^+_n)
\end{array}
$$

Show that the connecting homomorphisms associated with the top and bottom Mayer-Vietoris sequences are symmetric, i.e. $\Gamma_1 = - \Gamma_2$.

As a suggestion, it is also stated to use a previous exercise in which it was shown that replacing the pair $(S^n,E_n^-)$ by $(S^n, E_n^+)$ had the effect of multiplying $H_n(S^n)$ by $-1$. Before, to prove this I used the reflection map.

So far I have done the following (using the notation of Greenberg and Harper)

We have two MV sequences which are
$$
\dots \overset{\Gamma_1}{\longrightarrow} H_q(S^{n-1}) \overset{\Phi_1}{\longrightarrow} H_q(E_n^+) \oplus H_q(E_n^-) \overset{\Psi_1}{\longrightarrow} H_q(S^n) \overset{\Gamma_1}{\longrightarrow} H_{q-1} (S^{n-1}) \longrightarrow \dots 
$$
$$
\dots \overset{\Gamma_2}{\longrightarrow} H_q(S^{n-1}) \overset{\Phi_2}{\longrightarrow} H_q(E_n^-) \oplus H_q(E_n^+) \overset{\Psi_2}{\longrightarrow} H_q(S^n) \overset{\Gamma_2}{\longrightarrow} H_{q-1} (S^{n-1}) \longrightarrow \dots 
$$
obtained from the following commutative diagrams
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
\dots & \longrightarrow & H_q(S^{n-1}) & \overset{f_1}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(E^-_n) & \overset{g_1}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(E_n^-,S^{n-1}) &\overset{h_1}{\longrightarrow}  & H_{q-1} (S^{n-1}) & \longrightarrow & \dots  \\
 & & \alpha_1 \Big \downarrow & & \beta_1 \Big \downarrow & & \gamma_1 \Big \downarrow  & & \alpha_1 \Big \downarrow   \\
\dots &\longrightarrow & H_q(E^+_n) & \overset{f_1'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n) & \overset{g_1'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n, E_n^+) & \overset{h_1'}{\longrightarrow} & H_{q-1}(E_n^+) & \longrightarrow & \dots 
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
\dots & \longrightarrow & H_q(S^{n-1}) & \overset{f_2}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(E^+_n) & \overset{g_2}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(E_n^+,S^{n-1}) &\overset{h_2}{\longrightarrow}  & H_{q-1} (S^{n-1}) & \longrightarrow & \dots  \\
& & \alpha_2 \Big \downarrow & & \beta_2 \Big \downarrow & & \gamma_2 \Big \downarrow  & & \alpha_2 \Big \downarrow   \\
\dots &\longrightarrow & H_q(E^-_n) & \overset{f_2'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n) & \overset{g_2'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n, E_n^-) & \overset{h_2'}{\longrightarrow} & H_{q-1}(E_n^-) & \longrightarrow & \dots 
\end{array}
$$
where we have defined $\Phi_i = (\alpha_i , f_i) $, $\Psi_i = (-f_i' +\beta_i)$ and $\Gamma_i = h_i \gamma_i^{-1} g_i'$.

From the initial commuting diagram we have $\gamma_1^{-1} = a \circ \gamma_2^{-1} \circ a $. We also have therefore the following commuting diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
H_q(S^n ) & \overset{g_1'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n, E^+_n) & \overset{\gamma_1^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  & H_q(E_n^-,S^{n-1}) & \overset{h_1}{\longrightarrow} & H_{q-1}(S^{n-1})  \\
\mathrm{?}_1 \Big \downarrow & & a \Big \downarrow & & a \Big \downarrow & & \mathrm{?}_2 \Big \downarrow \\ 
H_q(S^n ) & \overset{g_2'}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(S^n, E^-_n) & \overset{\gamma_2^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} & H_q(E_n^+,S^{n-1}) & \overset{h_2}{\longrightarrow} & H_{q-1}(S^{n-1}) 
\end{array}
$$

My questions then are

1. As I mentioned before, to prove the suggestion that was offered I used the reflection map which in $H_n(S^n)$ is equivalent to multiplying by $-1$. However, the antipodal map leads to multiplication by $(-1)^{n+1}$ so why is it that both $(S^n, E^-_n ) \overset{r}{\longrightarrow} (S^n,E^+_n)$ and $(S^n, E^-_n ) \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} (S^n,E^+_n) $ both induce multiplication by $-1$ on $H_n(S^n)$?
2. Taking into consideration what is in the suggestion, we should have then $\mathrm{?}_1 = -1 $. How can I proceed from here to obtain $\mathrm{?}_2$?

Thank you for your help